# How to move all items one item forward in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to do the following (consider this list):

```
['Hello, 'Hi', 'Nice', Cool']
```

I would like to change 'Hi' to 'Love'

But, I wouldn't want it to stay that way:

```
['Hello, 'Love', 'Nice', Cool']
```

I'm trying to get ahead of the others, even cropping the last one, getting like this:

```
['Hello, 'Love', 'Hi', Nice']
```

Note that Hi passed one along with the entire list, that's what I want!

Anybody know? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not insert into list and then remove the last item ?

Comment: Because it's not always just one I need to replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the item into the desired position, and then remove the last item.

**Here is the code:**

```
# Starting list
x = ['Hello', "Hi", 'Nice', 'Cool']

items_to_insert = 'Love'
item_to_find = "Hi"

if item_to_find in x:
    x.insert( x.index(item_to_find), items_to_insert)
    x.pop()
    print(x)
else:
    print(f"{item_to_find} is not in the list")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['Hello', 'Love', 'Hi', 'Nice']
```

---

**Working with integers in the list:**

```py
x = ['Hello', 6, 'Nice', 'Cool']

items_to_insert = 'Love'
item_to_find = 6

if item_to_find in x:
    x.insert( x.index(item_to_find), items_to_insert)
    x.pop()
    print(x)
else:
    print(f"{item_to_find} is not in the list")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['Hello', 'Love', 6, 'Nice']
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem has already been solved, but in your solution there would also be a problem for me, it was my mistake not to inform, but sometimes there may be an integer in the list. But your answer will certainly be useful for me to save, I didn't know about this function. <3

Comment: It could work with integers. - Have updated my answer to show.

Comment: It really worked, and it worked better than before, ty <3

Comment: I have made a slight modification to the code - to check if the item is in the list. Because if you search for an `item_to_find` that is not in the list - well - it would cause an error. But the code above now lets you know that the item is not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
old_list = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Nice', 'Cool']
new_item_index = 1
new_item = 'Love'

new_list = old_list[0:new_item_index] + [new_item] + old_list[new_item_index+1:]
print(old_list)
print(new_list)
```

```
['Hello', 'Hi', 'Nice', 'Cool']
['Hello', 'Love', 'Hi', 'Nice']
```